# Why the PageViewer is not showing in Tablayout Android Xamarin?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, tabs

I created an Android Mobile Application using Xamarin and I started with a Sidemenu template, now I am trying to add Tabs in the Content page using Tablayout and Viewpager. The tabs are showing, however, it cannot show the Fragments i assigned per tab.

I already tried downloading some source codes, run the app and it works. However, when i try to do the same thing in the app i created. It does not work.

Here is the code in my MainActivity including the Page Adapter Class

```
namespace DeskMatePro
{
    [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity, NavigationView.IOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
    {
        ViewPager viewpager;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

            viewpager = FindViewById<Android.Support.V4.View.ViewPager>(Resource.Id.viewpager);

            Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar toolbar = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
            SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);


            if (viewpager.Adapter == null)
            {
                setupViewPager(viewpager);


            }
            else
            {
                viewpager.Adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
            }


            FloatingActionButton fab = FindViewById<FloatingActionButton>(Resource.Id.fab);
            fab.Click += FabOnClick;

            DrawerLayout drawer = FindViewById<DrawerLayout>(Resource.Id.drawer_layout);
            ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, Resource.String.navigation_drawer_open, Resource.String.navigation_drawer_close);
            drawer.AddDrawerListener(toggle);
            toggle.SyncState();

            NavigationView navigationView = FindViewById<NavigationView>(Resource.Id.nav_view);
            navigationView.SetNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

            var tabLayout = FindViewById<TabLayout>(Resource.Id.tabs);

            tabLayout.SetupWithViewPager(viewpager);
        }

        void setupViewPager(Android.Support.V4.View.ViewPager viewPager)
        {
            var adapter = new Adapter(SupportFragmentManager);
            adapter.AddFragment(new ContactsFragment(), "First Fragment");
            adapter.AddFragment(new HistoryFragment(), "Second Fragment");
            viewPager.Adapter = adapter;
            viewpager.Adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
            //viewpager.OffscreenPageLimit(4);
        }


        public override void OnBackPressed()
        {
            DrawerLayout drawer = FindViewById<DrawerLayout>(Resource.Id.drawer_layout);
            if (drawer.IsDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.Start))
            {
                drawer.CloseDrawer(GravityCompat.Start);
            }
            else
            {
                base.OnBackPressed();
            }
        }

        public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
        {
            MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
        {
            int id = item.ItemId;
            if (id == Resource.Id.action_settings)
            {
                return true;
            }

            return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        private void FabOnClick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            View view = (View)sender;
            Snackbar.Make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LengthLong)
                .SetAction("Action", (Android.Views.View.IOnClickListener)null).Show();
        }

        public bool OnNavigationItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
        {
            int id = item.ItemId;


            DrawerLayout drawer = FindViewById<DrawerLayout>(Resource.Id.drawer_layout);
            drawer.CloseDrawer(GravityCompat.Start);
            return true;
        }
        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }

    }

    class Adapter : Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentPagerAdapter
    {
        List<V4Fragment> fragments = new List<V4Fragment>();
        List<string> fragmentTitles = new List<string>();


        public Adapter(V4FragmentManager fm) : base(fm)
        {
        }

        public void AddFragment(V4Fragment fragment, String title)
        {
            fragments.Add(fragment);
            fragmentTitles.Add(title);


        }

        public override V4Fragment GetItem(int position)
        {
            return fragments[position];

        }

        public override int Count
        {
            get { return fragments.Count; }
        }

        public override Java.Lang.ICharSequence GetPageTitleFormatted(int position)
        {
            return new Java.Lang.String(fragmentTitles[position]);
        }


    }
```

Code for the app_bar_main (template)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu_dialpad" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Code for main content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">


    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:id="@+id/tabs" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/viewpager" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Code for History Fragment

```
namespace DeskMatePro.Fragments
{
    public class HistoryFragment : Fragment
    {
        public HistoryFragment()
        {

        }

        public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.tabhistory, container, false);
            return view;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In `content_main`, you need to set the `<LinearLayout>`'s `orientation` to `vertical`. It's `horizontal` by default, so the `<ViewPager>` is being pushed out the side by the `match_parent` width on the `<TabLayout>`. You might also want to set the `<ViewPager>`'s height to `match_parent`, but that's not really causing a problem, as is.

Comment: @MikeM. Thank you for your help. You saved my day :)